# Fill a list from another class

Tags: c#

I have these classes:

```
class Game
    {
        public List<Participant> Participants = new List<Participant>();
    }

class Participant
    {
        public int ChampionId { get; set; }
        public string SummonerName { get; set; }
        public int SummonerId { get; set; }
    }

public class APICalls
    {
        //private Game game;

        private string GetResponse(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        public void GetParticipants()
        {
            // create a string from the JSON output
            var jsonString = GetResponse("https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v3/positions/by-summoner/27528610?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            // fill the Participants list from the Game class with participants based on the contents of the jsonString variable
            Game.Participants = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(jsonString);


        }

    }
```

I want to fill my Participants list in the Game class with the GetParticipants method in the APICalls class. My problem is that I can't access the list from this class.

I would like to keep all my API code in one class file which is why I made this class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't do that because you don't have an instance of your `Game` class. Can there be only one `Game` at a time? then maybe you could make `Game` a so called Singleton.

Comment: I'd suggest having a return type for your functions, e.g. `public List<Participant> GetParticipants()`, that way you can declare an instance of `APICalls` where ever you want, and use `GetParticipants();` method to assign values manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create an object of `Game` and refer to `Participants` using `game.Participants` as shown below:

```
Game game = new Game();
game.Participants = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(jsonString);
```

Or

Make the Participants list static:

```
class Game
{
    public static List<Participant> Participants = new List<Participant>();
}
```

And access the `Participants` list it directly then using `Game.Participants`

Comment: I will only be using 1 game when the program runs until it stops again. In this case would you recommend making the participants list static? At the moment I am leaning towards this.

Comment: Ya. You can make it static. Like Tim Schmelter said, if you have multiple threads, you might run into problems.

Answer (score 2):

You need an instance of the `Game` class in order to use it's (non static) fields:

```
var game = new Game();
game.Participants = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(jsonString);
```

If you only want one instance you could make the field `static`, then your code works. But note that you might get problems if multiple threads access that list at the same time then.

Answer (score 0):

Participants is not a static property. You need to declare an instance of the class. You also appear to be trying to desieralise the JSON into a "Game" object, but then assign it to the Participants property. I've assumed that actually the JSON is returning a list of participants and amended accordingly, but that may not be the case.

```
Game game = new Game();
game.Participants = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Participant>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Yes, The JSON returns a list of participants.

Comment: ok well try deserialising it the way I've suggested. Trying to deserialise a list into a single object of a different type is unlikely to work.